# Make a Batch File Separate Words to Different Lines

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am need creating a batch file to take an input and separate the content in different lines to a file.

For example:

```
Apple Banana Orange
```

And make the file look like:

```
Apple
Banana
Orange
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please mention the platform you are using - Windows / UNIX

Comment: I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a script based on the following to ask for input and write the different items to the file `result.txt`

```
@echo off
set /p fruit=Give input:

for %%f in (%fruit%) do (
  echo %%f >> result.txt
)
```

If `result.txt` already exists, it will append the new items to the existing file. If you do not want that, then just delete `result.txt` at the beginning of the script.

You can either enter the input by hand, or take input from a file using something like `fruit.bat < input.txt`

Comment: Glad to help and welcome to StackOverflow. Since you are new here, do not forget to read about [upvoting/accepting answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) if this answer has helped.